# MySQL won't recognize MD5

Tags: php, mysql, md5

One quick question..

I am trying to see if an MD5 password is the same with the MySQL entry but I fail badly atm. (It works OK on my offline server though..)

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong in this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".trim($_POST['username'])."' AND `password` = '".md5(trim($_POST['password']))."' LIMIT 0,1;
```

Thanks!

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong is directly injecting posted data into an SQL statement.

Comment: For starters you're injecting variables directly into your query making your code very vulnerable towards SQL injection. Secondly, you should be using prepared statements and bind variables. Thirdly, have you tried to output your query and paste it directly into your database to see what the error is? Imagine if `username` was `admin' OR 1 = 1 --`. Suddenly I'd be logged in as the user with the username "admin" without knowing the password. Cool!

Comment: Are you getting an errors?

Comment: Please post you full code, at least the full php statement you're executing.

Comment: It seems like something's missing. Variables in single quoted strings are not expanded.

Comment: I tried to run the MySQL query with md5(digitsgohere) and I get no results. And thank you for the injection notice.

Comment: As long as we're making suggestions, `md5` is not considered a secure password hash.  Has not been for years.  You should not be writing new code that uses it, if you have the option use bcrypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they have explained in the comments, you want to be using either Mysqli or the MySQL PDO class ... Personally I use PDO, which can help a lot with security, and it's not too hard to get your head around.

Here's a tutorial that helped me:
http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

If you want to do it the way you have posted, could you post the full php MySQL statement, and we may be able to point you in the right direction :D

Oh, and another point, you don't really want ot be using MD5 either ... It's really vulnerable to rainbow attacks ... Try using Blowfish with salts ... Here's a tutorial for that: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/blowfish-crypt/

Comment: That Blowfish Crypt tutorial was chaotic -.-" Although I looked it up a bit more and people seem to suggest password_hash() instead

Comment: It's fun watching people learn ... And I just learned something new too :D ... I might swap over to `password_hash()`, gunna read into it a bit though, cos there is some comments about earlier versions of it being unstable